# Protocol "tftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl in beaglebone linux

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, bitbake, tftp, curlpp

I have try a c++ program using curlpp libraries in my VM, my intention is when i execute the program, i can get a file via tftp.

I tested this program on the VM , this program managed to get a file from another VM.
However when i run this program in beaglebone yocto , it prompt following error:

```
Protocol "tftp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

FYI,the beaglebone can the ping and greb file from VM using busybox tftp.
I get the curlpp recipes from https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/curlpp/curlpp_0.8.1.bb. Am i missing anything on this?

Comment: Rebuild `curl` with `tftp` support: http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-support/curl/curl_7.71.1.bb?h=master#n47

Comment: Thanks , i saw my curl recipes -> curl_7.68.0.bb  do mentioned PACKAGECONFIG[tftp] = "--enable-tftp,--disable-tftp," any different between curl_7.68.0.bb and  curl_7.71.1.bb?

Comment: `PACKAGECONFIG[option]` just means that `option` can be selected, it does not mean it is. You need to add `option` to `PACKAGECONFIG` for the option to be selected. So, add `tftp` to `PACKAGECONFIG` of your curl recipe (in a bbappend; that's the cleanest way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-curl = " tftp" in local.conf